# Is there a clean way to handle unit (degrees, radians, etc.) conversions in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am working on a plug-in to a mapping application that has quite a few classes that have a ton of options for units.  I feel like I have a pretty good handle on maintaining order within the model.For example, the Angle class has properties for Degrees and Radians and automatically updates each other.  The Altitude  class does the same thing for feet MSL, meters MSL, meters HAE, etc.

However, when I get into the WPF side, I would like to have any data entry points have a TextBox so that they can enter in values but also display the units.  I am currently using Caliburn Micro to use composition and it has been a total game changer for me.  In the past, I would have hacked together some sort of enum and mapped them to each individual viewmodel with potentially a lot of code duplication and definitely making the code brittle.  I don't want to have some sort of SelectedUnit feature in the Model because I feel that a string representation of the units is only valuable to the view.

Any ideas to implement a clean mapping between a value and its units that will allow for composition?

Comment: If you don't know in the view model what unit the user is entering, then how can your application make sense of the data? Surely the units used are as important as the values entered?

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information here - what kind of mapping are you talking about? What's in your model? What's in your viewmodel? What's in your view? What do you want to display in your view? What's the exact problem you are having? The question is a bit to vague as far as I can see... as for the UOM handling: a lot of ERP systems store a 'base' unit of measure and then make any other UOM calculations relative to the base unit. This means you can just store the raw value in a particular class and store a UOM code/reference which is responsible for conversion. You need not hard code

Comment: @Charleh The main third party library I am using sort of dictates the base measurement requirement.  To make things more clear, I created a .Net wrapper and strongly typed different units to add some sanity (the C++ code is littered with unions and really encourages you to screw up).  For now, I am assuming a base requirement but I know that they are going to add the requirement to change units in an upcoming sprint. So, once they go into their user settings and change a UOM setting, I would like for the code to automatically fix the values and the string for UOM.

Comment: @Charleh Not sure what the best approach is to handle this as simply as possible.  Should I use the event aggregator and handle the same message across many, many viewmodels and write the same code many, many times or is their a more elegant way to handle this.  t

Comment: @Charleh Hit the wrong key at the end.  The whole premise of the question is really seeing how to handle these global sorts of problems in a clean, responsible way.  I know a lot of "wrong ways" to do it and am trying to wrap my head around best practices.  Additionally, sometimes you just need to hear that there isn't a "silver bullet" to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the info - if I understand correctly, this 3rd party lib only stores 1 UOM and you have wrapped it with some .NET stuff in order to make working with multiple UOMs easier? If so then you have strongly typed some conversion code which would probably be better as a relative conversion. This way you wouldn't need to change anything in your views, your model/VM would just dictate what the UOM is and your bindings would remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the C++ lib does and why you needed to wrap it, but if you have a base unit of measure somewhere, then it is pretty trivial to convert into another UOM using a relative value (exchange rate)

Doing so means that your model doesn't need to change and can expose a single property for the converted value and a single property for the base value. Changing the UOM would cause the converted UOM value to change

e.g.

```
class SomeModel 
{ 
    // You can assume that the base UOM has a conversion rate of 1
    UnitOfMeasure BaseUnitOfMeasure { get; }

    decimal BaseQuantity { get; }

    UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

    decimal Quantity { get { return UnitOfMeasure.Convert(BaseQuantity, BaseUnitOfMeasure); } }

   // or if you are assuming base UOM is conversion rate of 1 then you can just use
   // decimal Quantity { get { return UnitOfMeasure.Convert(BaseQuantity); } }
}
```

Then binding becomes simple:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" /><TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitOfMeasure.Name}" />
```

Your view doesn't need to change to display a new unit of measure, you just assign a new UOM to the `UnitOfMeasure` property, and any subsequent calls to `Quantity` return the new converted rate.

Obviously I'm leaving out a fair bit of notification code but you can fill that in

Does this make things easier or have you already considered this?

I know that you don't want to 'pollute' your model with a UOM string, but the UOM is part of the model really. If not it's at least a ViewModel concern but I wouldn't bother changing your views to accommodate when you can do it quite efficiently without

Comment: Thanks Charleh.  I'll have to do some unit testing and see how it shakes out.

Comment: I've got a demo project if you would like it

Comment: That would be awesome.  BTW - I have just started reading Dependency Injection in .Net and am in the confusion phase right now...

Comment: Ah ok - any particular framework, or just the concept in general?

Comment: I've uploaded the sample proj here - you will need to let NuGet grab the dependencies as I've not included them (just CM1.52) http://www.filedropper.com/uomexample

Comment: Great example.  So, I am envisioning a "configuration" view with approximately ten different UOMs.  I was thinking that any changes would use the EventAggregator so that any ViewModels that reference the UOMs would auto-populate.  Right now, I don't have a requirement for them to change the UOM everywhere they input data (although not a bad idea).  I suppose I could use a BaseVM to automatically register and handle this UOM config message.  In contrast, just read briefly about the Ambient Context and wonder if I should use something like that instead of the EventAggregator.

Comment: Well - I've put the UOM data on the model object, but yes you could just place the 'work' UOM for a particular type of result into the global context and pick up that particular UOM when the VM loads (or update it via aggregator). It may be that you have some UOM 'sets' since it sounds like you have different types of measurements which may have a particular subset of UOMs available (it sounds like this is what you were attempting when wrapping the c++ in .NET types with explicit conversions built in). This could all be stored in the global context.

Comment: I took a look at your blog and I think I am in the mode you describe in "Patterns and Practices" - some things just don't feel right.  I have recently realized that I have been writing bad code with Caliburn.Micro and Ninject - just putting the coupled code in different spots.  My project will have various sets of UOMs and I am hoping that I can make a clean decoupled solution.  I am still waiting to have the project officially turned on and just testing the waters conceptually right now.  My main learning focus has been using Blend - I can't believe I have been hand jamming XAML in VS;)

Comment: I always hand jam XAML in VS! Doing any UI work is the UI/UX developers job (unless you are the UI/UX developer!)

Comment: I am the UI/UX Developer, Developer, Domain Expert, Scrum Master, Product Owner, etc.